# Typescript factory without constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, factory

I recently came across the following code:

```
class PizzaMaker {
    create(event: { name: string; toppings: string[] }) {
        return { name: event.name, toppings: event.toppings };
    }
}

const pizzaMaker = new PizzaMaker();

const pizza = pizzaMaker.create({
    name: 'Inferno',
    toppings: ['cheese', 'peppers'],
});

console.log(pizza);
// Output: { name: 'Inferno', toppings: [ 'cheese', 'peppers' ] }
```

How is PizzaMaker getting instantiated without a constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any environment that supports native classes (e.g. ES6 and onwards), constructors are automatically made if not provided: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

> If you don't provide your own constructor, then a default constructor will be supplied for you. If your class is a base class, the default constructor is empty.

For environments that don't support native classes (e.g. ES5 and prior), TypeScript instead does the work of generating a default constructor for you:

From [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCWAvRYCyYDWBTATtA3gLABQ0Z0wOWYALlgBRYBuWAdjQFwHStgC2WLhBo54rAOYBuaDQD2AB3ljxEISOUBtALrQAvgEoCJciehUaAVxytuvAV2ZsaAOjtYANDIVKJq6I-ZnOUVlGF1JY3JdEmjiIA):

```
class PizzaMaker {
    create(event: { name: string; toppings: string[] }) {
        return { name: event.name, toppings: event.toppings };
    }
}
```

The emit JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
var PizzaMaker = /** @class */ (function () {
    // Note: this empty function is the default constructor
    function PizzaMaker() {
    }
    PizzaMaker.prototype.create = function (event) {
        return { name: event.name, toppings: event.toppings };
    };
    return PizzaMaker;
}());
```